# This prolog program shows error and i m unable to detect the error

Tags: prolog, palindrome, visual-prolog

I am trying to create a Palindrome Programme on Visual Prolog that checks user input number.
I somehow wrote some codes BUT it shows error and it is difficult for me to remove errors.
**Please,
      I need help on this code.**

**DOMAINS**
*Num,Temp,Reverse=integer*

**PREDICATES**
*palindrome*

**CLAUSES**
*

```
palindrome:-
   Reverse=:=0,
   write("Enter a number to check ."),
   readint(Number),
   Temp=Number

loop(Temp=/=0) :-
   Reverse=Reverse*10,
   Reverse=Reverse+ Temp mod 10,
   Temp=Temp/10, 
   false.
(Number=:=Reverse->
   write("The Number ",Number," is a Palindrome "),
   fail ; Number=/=Reverse->
   write("The Number ",Number," is not a Palindrome.") ; .
```

**GOAL**
palindrome.

Comment: Reverse=Reverse*10 is False condition. Use IS operator if you are going to set some numerical value to a variable.

Comment: Visual Prolog should also accept more standard Prolog. Do you agree on some answer more 'Prolog like' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In writing a prolog program, it can be helpful to write down a clear, specific problem statement and *decompose* the problem. Something like:

> A number is palindromic, IF it is an integer,
>   and IF its digits are identical when reversed, ignoring its sign.

That leads us to this *interface* predicate which pretty much recapitulates the problem statement, thus:

```
%---------------------
% the public interface
%---------------------
palindromic_number(X) :- % A number is palindromic if
  integer(X) ,           % - it is an integer, and
  X >= 0 ,               % - it is greater than or equal to zero, and
  reverse_digits(X,0,X)  % - its decimal value is the same if you reverse its decimal digits
  .                      % ... OR ...
palindromic_number(X) :- % it is palindromic, if
  integer(X) ,           % - it is an integer, and
  X < 0 ,                % - it is less than zero, and
  X1 is - X ,            % - its absolute value
  palindromic_number(X)  % - is palindromic
  .                      % Easy!
```

Now, all we have to do is figure out how to reverse the digits of a number. Given that we've eliminated dealing with the sign, above, it's easy: Strip digits from the right end, adding them to the left end of the result, until we hit zero.

A useful idiom in prolog is to have a public predicate that fronts a private workder predicate that often takes an *accumulator* wherein the final result is built up as you recursively work the problem. Also, in this case (and many others), there is usually a *general* case and one or a few *special* cases. Here, our special case, which terminates the compuation is when the source value is zero.

Which leads us to this definition of "how to reverse the digits of a number":

```
% ---------------------
% The worker predicate
% ---------------------
reverse_digits(0,T,T).    % once we hit zero, the accumulator has the reversed number. Unify the accumulator with the desired result.
reverse_digits(X,T,Y) :-  % Otherwise...
  X > 0 ,                 % - if X > 0,
  X1 is X /   10 ,        % - compute the next X
  D  is X mod 10 ,        % - compute the nexst digit
  T1 is 10*T + D ,        % - scale the accumulator and add the digit
reverse_digits(X1,T1,Y)   % - recurse down.
.                         % - easy!
```

Another approach, of course, would be to convert the number into a string (which is a list of individual characters), reverse that list using the built-in `reverse/2` predicate and unify that with the original value. I doubt that is what your instructor is looking for, however.